# How to determine y_predicted at certain x after fitting the data with curve_fit from scipy.optimize?

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I fitted the data with curve_fit method from scipy.optimize using a polynomial function.
How do I get the y_predicted values at x=10, 7.5, 5, 2.5?

```
'''Define function for fitting'''
def fit_function(x, a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
   return a*x**6+b*x**5+c*x**4+d*x**3+e*x**2+f*x+g

'''Find optimal parameters'''
optimal_param,cov=curve_fit(fit_function, x, y, maxfev=100000)

'''Print optimal parameters''' 
print(optimal_param)

'''Calculate prediction'''
y_predicted = fit_function(x, optimal_param[0], optimal_param[1], optimal_param[2], 
                           optimal_param[3], optimal_param[4], optimal_param[5], optimal_param[6])

'''Calculate error'''

plt.plot(x, y, marker='D', linestyle='')
plt.plot(x, y_predicted, marker='', linestyle='--')`
```

[click to see the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdWKg.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the official doc
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html
You can use the following function

```
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c
```

So to predict y just use

```
 func(x, *popt)
```